# How to Update a div tag in Master Page using a button click in Content page? or Wise versa

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to Update a div tag in Master Page using a button click in Content page? or Wise versa

Comment: See the answer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371098/how-to-change-master-page-value-from-child-page/2371134#2371134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get the data to be updated in a postback only? You can either do it using javascript if you get the data to be updated in the client side, or bring it to the client side on a postback and use some javascript method to update. If you get the data as some attribute of a server side class, ou can use server tags (as in classic ASP) in the master page like `<div id="updatableDiv"><%=myClass.PropertWithUpdatedValue%></div>` in the master page.

Update: refer [How to change master page value from child page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371098/how-to-change-master-page-value-from-child-page/2371134#2371134)