# How to change master page value from child page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to change master page some label value from child page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a property like this in master page:

```
public string MyText { get {return lbl.Text;} set {lbl.Text = value;}}
```

Once you do that you can use the same property in content page like:

```
((MasterPageTypeName)Page.Master ).MyText = "test";
```

and you are done!

Comment: this whole thing is right. The string MyText is getting set to whatever i am passing but its bot updating on the master page. Master Page still shows the same old message. And how can i implement the same functionality for Menu.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine,just need to change:

```
((MasterPageTypeName)Page.MasterPage ).MyText = "test";
```

to `((MasterPageTypeName)Page.Master ).MyText = "test";`

that's it,you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just add '@mastertype' to the child page .aspx declaratively. This creates a strongly-typed reference to the masterpage.

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masters/SourcePage.master" %>
```