# Set DropDownList selected value on master page from child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, master-pages

Attempting something like

```
public string MyText { get {return lbl.Text;} set {lbl.Text = value;}}
```

taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371098/how-to-change-master-page-value-from-child-page) ends in an exception:

```
public string change_ddlArea { get { return ddlArea.SelectedItem.Text; } set { ddlArea.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true; } }
```

> --> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Using these normally cause the same error:

```
this.ddlEnergyType.Items.FindByValue(resourceTypeVal).Selected = true;
((DropDownList)Master.FindControl("ddlArea")).Items.FindByValue("all").Selected = true;
```

I'm having difficulty finding an answer to this problem on google. It *should* work, given if a label manipulation does, moving to a ddl would as well?

The one difference that could be the problem is when trying to call this.. (in the 2nd code block) I use

```
Master.change_ddlArea = sendoff_area;
```

and in the aformentioned link it is done like so

```
((MasterPageTypeName)Page.MasterPage ).MyText = "test";
//so mine would look like this:
((GAWMaster)_default.Master).change_ddlArea = "all";
```

however intellisense is missing the '.Master' - putting it in causes the information to appear: an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property....

tl,dr: halp

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure your page derives from a Master Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is VERY confusing to say the least.  It's very simple to do what your title is asking:

First in your `MasterPage` code behind do:

```
public string change_ddlArea
{
    get { return ddlArea.SelectedItem.Value; }
    set { ddlArea.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true; }
}
```

Then in your child page define your `MasterPage` type so that it can 'see' the `change_ddlArea` property of the `MasterPage`.  [See here for more reference info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx)

```
<%@ MasterType virtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>
```

Then in  your code on your child page you should be able to just do:

```
Master.change_ddlArea(someValue);
```

The value you are setting **MUST** exist or you will get an object reference error.  Make sure your `DropDownList` is loaded correctly and you are not doing things out of order.  Also, if your not using `ViewState` and doing a `PostBack`, make sure you have rebuilt your `DropDownList` before setting the value.

Comment: I think my problem lies in that it is existing with a zero value, not that my code was faulty. Apologies for the poor explanation. You answered the question I suppose~

Answer (score 1):

A master page in .NET is just a class, right? Let's take a look at it this way. Your page uses that master page. But this means that your page *has* that master page, not *is* that master page. Therefore, theoretically you should be able to get a reference to that master page from your page. Let's use other words to make it more clear:

```
 // This is like the master page
 public class Hand
 {
 }

 // This is like the page. Please notice that a human **has** hands, but a human **is** not hand.
 public class Human
 {
     Hand leftHand = new Handl();
 }
```

Now, think. Is it possible to get to fingers through an instance of human class? Do you see the logic here? Of course you can get a reference to the Hand class, and from there, you can get reference to fingers:

```
 Human jack = new Human();
 jack.Hand.Fingers["SmallFinger"].Cut();
```

Now what if your hand is a special type of hand (Special master page which has a label in it?). All you need is a cast

```
 ((ExpensiveHand)jack.Hand).Rings.Steal();
```

That's the logic between a page and a master page.